# Spring JPA: Association requirement when joining tables

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have two tables, ORDER and STATUS.
For every change in the orders in ORDER table, we enter the audit into STATUS table with lastUpdatedDateTime.

Sometimes, I just need to fetch order detail and sometimes I need latest status along with order details.

How should I design my entity and how should I join tables when needed?
Do I need to add associations to join table(using criteria builder)?
If I add associations, status data from STATUS table will be pulled even when not needed (e.g. when doing findBy on ORDER where we just need order details)?

Also when I display to the User the orders, they should look like below. Need status and lastUpdatedBy in the Order object

```
[
    {
        "OrderId": "1",
        "product": "pen",
        "status": "IP",
        "lastUpdatedBy": "user1"
    },
    {
        "OrderId": "1",
        "product": "book",
        "status": "CP",
        "lastUpdatedBy": "user2"
    }
]
```

I have tried using association and criteria builder to join tables.

Questions:

1. A right way to design my entites
2. how to join tables to fetch the top record from status table for a given order.
   (P.S i need to use predicates as I have dynamic where clause requirement)

Sample SQL

```
Select f, o.statusCode, o.lastUpdatedBy
from FX_ORDER f left join ORDER o
ON f.ORDER_ID = o.ORDER_ID
and f.SEQUENCE= o.SEQUENCE
where o.statusCode = 'IP'
and o.lastUpdatedDateTime in (select max(s.lastUpdatedDateTime)
   from ORDER s where
    s.ORDER_ID = o.ORDER_ID
    and s.SEQUENCE= o.SEQUENCE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information, it seems like you have a one-to-many relationship between ORDER and STATUS tables, where an ORDER can have multiple STATUS records.

To design your entities, you can create two classes: Order and Status. The Order class will have a collection of Status objects as a member variable to represent the one-to-many relationship. The Order class will also have attributes for OrderId and product, and the Status class will have attributes for statusCode, lastUpdatedBy, and lastUpdatedDateTime. You can then use JPA annotations to map these classes to the corresponding tables in the database.

When you want to fetch order details with the latest status, you can use a query that joins the ORDER and STATUS tables and selects the top record from the STATUS table for each ORDER record.Check below example query

```
    SELECT o.OrderId, o.product, s.statusCode, s.lastUpdatedBy
FROM ORDER o
LEFT JOIN STATUS s ON o.OrderId = s.OrderId
AND s.lastUpdatedDateTime = (
    SELECT MAX(s2.lastUpdatedDateTime)
    FROM STATUS s2
    WHERE s2.OrderId = o.OrderId
)
```

This query joins the ORDER and STATUS tables on the OrderId column and uses a subquery to select the latest STATUS record for each ORDER record. The LEFT JOIN ensures that all ORDER records are included in the result, even if there are no corresponding STATUS records.

To use this query with dynamic where clause requirements, you can create a JPA CriteriaQuery object and add predicates to it based on the search criteria.Here's an example

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Order> query = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
Root<Order> orderRoot = query.from(Order.class);
Join<Order, Status> statusJoin = orderRoot.join("statuses", JoinType.LEFT);
query.multiselect(
    orderRoot.get("OrderId"),
    orderRoot.get("product"),
    statusJoin.get("statusCode"),
    statusJoin.get("lastUpdatedBy")
);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(cb.equal(statusJoin.get("statusCode"), "IP"));
query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
query.orderBy(cb.desc(statusJoin.get("lastUpdatedDateTime")));

List<Order> result = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @AselMeemeduma. As the multiselect is selecting statusCode and lastUpdatedBy from STATUS table, and at the end we are collecting the data in a list of ORDERs. As order does not have any fields like statusCode/lastUpdatedBy how will it capture the column response?

Comment: Should I create a pojo which has all fields of ORDER(as i need them all) and have statusCode and lastUpdatedBy in it?

Comment: where are we getting the max column from subQuery in the above criteria and how to put join columns?